# How to get python's json module to cope with right quotation marks?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load a utf-8 encoded json file using python's json module. The file contains several [right quotation marks, encoded as `E2 80 9D`](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128). When I call

```
json.load(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

I receive the message:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 212068: character maps to

How can I convince the json module to decode this properly?

EDIT: Here's a minimal example:

```
[
  {
    "aQuote": "“A quote”"
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you have broken JSON in the first place? Can you fix whatever caused that instead of trying to post-process the broken file?

Comment: Python should handle this (curly quotes or other utf-8 encoded text in a json file) automatically.  [MCVE] please?

Comment: @wim, see the edit.

Comment: That's not a [MCVE].  It doesn't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `encoding` in the signature of `json.load`. The solution should be simply:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    x = json.load(f)
```